# How to mute local audio playback while still receiving raw audio data with Agora API?

Tags: unity-game-engine, agora.io

I'm trying to play back raw audio data from an Agora remote stream through an AudioSource in Unity. For this, I have to first disable the default playback method used by the Agora SDK. I have tried `MuteAllRemoteAudioStreams` but this stops the API from receiving remote audio data altogether.

I have also tried `AdjustPlaybackSignalVolume` and `AdjustAudioMixingVolume`, which successfully mute the audio playback but this also makes the `OnPlaybackAudioFrameHandler` callback receive empty audio frames, stopping me from accessing raw audio data.

`SetAudioPlaybackDeviceMute` simply mutes the playback device, which is not what I am looking for.

Is there a way to only mute the playback of remote streams while also being able to access raw audio data?

Answer (score 0):

Try mRtcEngine.AdjustPlaybackSignalVolume(0);
This will turn the playback volume from the channel, but your AudioSource volume is not affected.

If you have other issues, please come chat with us and search for answers in our slack group:
https://agoraiodev.slack.com/messages/unity-help-me